# Is there a way to style footer button white

Tags: css, margin

I'm asked to style footer button to color white but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is incorrect or something is wrong with the code.

I've tried to code the button on its own but it seems it is nor right

```
footer {
    width: calc(100% - 2em);
    z-index: 500;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 1em;
  }

  footer button.mdc-icon-button {
    margin: 0.5em;
    color: white;        
  }

</style>
```

```
<div>
  <h2>abdurrahman abdulwahab</h2>
  <div class ="user-photo mdc-elevation--z3">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150">        
  </div>
  <div class="details mdc-elevation--z3">language</div>
  <div class="messages"></div>
</div>

<footer>
  <button class="btn-address mdc-icon-button material-icons">contact_support</button>
  <button class="btn-phone mdc-icon-button material-icons">perm_phone_msg</button>
  <button class="btn-birthdate mdc-icon-button material-icons">calendar_today</button>
</footer>
```

I expect to know how to style the footer so as to make only the button color white and not include div above the footer.

Comment: you want footer buttons background color to be white or text color?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to set the background to white and not the text colour, as is the case currently.

If you are trying to set the background to white, you need to set `background: white;` as `color` sets the text-colour.

Bear in mind you will need to either remove `color` or update the value to something other than "white".

Comment: What I discovered in the result is that the DIV above the footer is affected with the white color which I will like to separate from the footer

Comment: Are you referring to the background color?

Comment: The default backgrould colour is white. Unless you have specified a background colour on the `<div>` it will be white.  But it will inherit it's background colour from a parent HTML tag/class/id if that has been set.

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, you can style the button inline using the style="attribute" route. However, it's best to try to keep the styling in the CSS. In your HTML, add the class "button," and in your css styling, use the css attribute "background-color:#FFFFFF".

It should look like this:

```html
<style>
.button {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: black;
}
</style>
```

You can change the class name I used here to something a little more specific to what you're editing, that way it doesn't blend in with other CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the CSS code which affects only the button styles inside the footer:

```
<style>    
    footer button {
      background-color: #fff;
      color: #000;
    }
</style>
```

Assuming, you want the font colors of your button is black.